# Datepicker does not work in the modals. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using the bootstrap daterangepicker.js library, to generate a calendar in the text fields with the "date" class. I have two text field outside of the modal where it works perfectly, but the texts fields with the class "date1" and "date2" that are in the modal does not work.

I need a good solution to validate two dates, to which I want to validate which date is the major.

Why does this happen and what can I do?

```
 $('.date').daterangepicker({
        "singleDatePicker": true,
        "opens": "right",
 })

 $('.date1').daterangepicker({
        "singleDatePicker": true,
        "opens": "right",
    })

 $('.date').daterangepicker({
        "singleDatePicker": true,
        "opens": "right",
    })


<div ng-app="myApp">
 <input type='text' class='date'>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModal.html">
 <div class="modal-header">
   <h3 class="modal-title">Modal title</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
     date1
     <input type='text' class='date1' id='date1'>
    date2
    <input type='text' class='date2' id='date1'>
 </div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="close(true)">OK</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="close('modalInstanceOne')">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="button" value="Show modal" ng-click="showModal()" />
</div>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/q24rmsbn/

Comment: Why do you mix an unnecessary jQuery with Angular?

Comment: may be it is not related to your question but try to avoid using same id for multiple element. You used id as date1 for both input.date1  and input.date2.

Comment: rJ7 thank you! solved

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular Directive, it's recommended way to handle this https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive. Because MyCtrl run before the modal is render and appended to DOM.

Updated:
Here how we handle with directive: (basic one)
http://fiddle.jshell.net/q24rmsbn/1/

Comment: Could you help me with this please, I do not know how in a directive validate the 2 text fields...

Comment: If you don't want to use directive, you can create a separate controller for modal, here you are http://fiddle.jshell.net/wfmxyL2L/4/

Comment: Great, but can you give me an example, how to solve what I need to do with a directive?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with you code is that element **$('.date1')** and **$('.date2')** does not exist in the dom when you are trying to bind datepicker with them.

For solution you can bind the datepicker functionality when the modal is rendered i.e the elements are in the DOM.

To use this you will have to upgrade angular-ui bootstrap version to 0.13

from this version the object returned by $modal.open returns have the function rendered which is called when the modal is rendered.

so your code will change like.

```
 $scope.showModal = function() {
      modalInstanceOne = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModal.html',
        scope: modalScope
      });

      modalInstanceOne.rendered.then(function() {

        $('.date1').daterangepicker({
          "singleDatePicker": true,
          "opens": "right",
        })

        $('.date2').daterangepicker({
          "singleDatePicker": true,
          "opens": "right",
        })
      });
    }   
  });
```

Working fiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/pufd9413/

Answer (score 0):

Add a controller to your modal in html

just like this

```
 <div class="modal-header" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
```

Updated fiddle:

**Edit link:**

http://fiddle.jshell.net/wfmxyL2L/1/

Comment: I have a problem with this solution, because if I do, it will reload the controller 2 times. Which is not optimal.

Comment: That is true, the way I usually work around these problems is creating separate controller for popup and then you can $emit data between two controllers.

Comment: With my current structure, how can I fix it? I do not know much about angular.

Answer (score -1):

it is issue with z-index try this.

```
  $('.date').on('show.daterangepicker', function(e){
      var modalZindex = $(e.target).closest('.modal').css('z-index');
      $('.daterangepicker').css('z-index', modalZindex+1);
  });
```